Remove desktop icons Ubuntu 24.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 as an upgrade from 22.04 on an Alienware pc. Went well. Desktop remained free of icons (as I like). I then did a clean install on an older Gateway pc. Went well except the desktop was full of icons. I tried a tweak from Ask Ubuntu which seemed to work. Several days later however, after "messing around" trying to network the two pcs (which works nicely now), the desktop icons reappeared on the Gateway and for the first time on the Alienware. I have no idea why. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.I need to get them off of there.
